# rethinkdb index-rebuild complains python driver is missing

Tags: database, rethinkdb

Ran into this error when trying to run rethinkdb rebuild command:

> Error when launching 'rethinkdb-index-rebuild': No such file or
>   directory The rethinkdb-index-rebuild command depends on the RethinkDB
>   Python driver, which must be installed. If the Python driver is
>   already installed, make sure that the PATH environment variable
>   includes the location of the backup scripts, and that the current user
>   has permission to access and run the scripts.

Yet I have the rethinkdb python module installed and path setup properly:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rethinkdb in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages Cleaning up...

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a feature implemented in a newer version of the python module. Solved it by:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade rethinkdb
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `rethinkdb-index-rebuild` script is not in your `PATH`, you might be able to invoke the `index-rebuild` command as

```
python -mrethinkdb._index_rebuild
```

Comment: This is helpful to use the rethinkdb driver installed in a virtual environment.